# I want to use sytem call write() without deleting data from the file

Tags: c, posix

For example if i had a file like this:

"Hello World" and i want to user the system call write() in C to put "bad" in the middle.

Like : "Hello bad world"

But all i can do now is  "Hello bad w"

Comment: `write()` is not a system call (and it's not a standard C function either, I think you're asking about the POSIX function?)

Comment: @FelixPalmen he probably is. Anyway, I voted to close as its unclear what OP is asking.

Comment: Then, what you want to do is **insert** something into a file. You **think** the solution is `write()`, but what makes you sure about that? Why not approach the problem with standard C functions like `fwrite()`? A first hint: you **can't** insert in a file. You have to rewrite the remainder of the file yourself.

Comment: Find the size of the file to know where the middle is. Open a new file and copy up to the middle of the old file to the new file using `fread` and `fwrite`. Now `fwrite` "bad " (it seems to need that space) to the new file and copy the rest of the old file.

Comment: @jxh: which filesystem lets you "fragment" a file into arbitrarily-sized chunks and then "link" arbitrarily-sized chunks into a single file? I can see how you could do that with block-sized chunks and direct disk access, but I don't know of any fs which exposes block lists...

Comment: @jxh: i think you'll find that sparseness is limited ti exact multiples of a block.

Comment: @jxh such as...?

Comment: @jxh: "• Files that are less than the record size are written as a single file system block (FSB) of variable size in **multiples of disk sectors (512B)**
• Files that are larger than the record size are stored in multiple FSBs equal to record size." (Emphasis added)

Comment: @rici: Interesting solutions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80429/append-huge-files-to-each-other-without-copying-them

Comment: @jxh: no answer to that question actually avoids copying except the one using losetup, which requires the filesizes to be multiples of a disk sector. As does ZFS although I didn't think it was useful to point that out again. Now, you could write your own filesystem using FUSE (or even as a kernel module) which added a permutation of variable-sized chunks as a façade over another filesystem, but I don't believe that "write your own FS" is really an answer to this question. Still, if it makes you happy, I'll agree it's possible.

Comment: @FelixPalmen we have to use write() because its an  sort of operating systems course , so they dont let us students use C functions , only open() write() read(), pipe, fork, etc... I guess i have to create a whole new file and copy "Hello" then write "bad" then copy the rest.. or something like that